# How to change 2-step card response into 1-step?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I'm developing a program in Java Card.
sometimes when I send a command to card, it responses as "0X61 0Xxx" which means there exist a response with 0Xxx length and I should answer to get it.

My question is, how can I avoid this kind of responses and get the answer at once?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your card support `T=1` protocol (you can find out from it's ATR [here](http://www.ruimtools.com/atr.php))? If it does -- do you actually connect using this protocol (it depends on the way you are talking with the card)? Do you get this 0x61xx status every time the card response contains data (or does it depend on the actual command APDU -- i.e. what does 'sometimes' mean)?

Comment: @vlp In fact I get this message once in ten commands and it does not return in many cases I write functions in my applet! Does it mean I can use a proper notation in my applet or send proper APDU not to get it? Does my card support T=1 ?

Comment: @MJay Dear Mr Jalali, the applet in my answer returns `6CXX` instead of `61XX`. Maybe you want to un-mark it.

Comment: @Abraham I think T=1 is answer ;)

Comment: @MJay Can you share the card ATR to be sure it does not support `T=1` protocol? Using `T=0` you should be able to avoid the `GET RESPONSE` mechanism for [APDU cases](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx#table4) 1,2 and 3 (but it can't be done for case 4). Case 4 is when you call both (`setIncomingAndReceive()` and `setOutgoing()` during a single `process()` call -- including variants of `setOutgoing()` like `setOutgoingAndSend()`)...Good luck!

Comment: @vlp Thanks for your help, my ATR is 3B6800000073C8401200 and I parsed it on the website you introduced. That's correct that my card is T=0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends!

Sometimes you receive `61XX` because you are communicating with an applet that is written as such! I mean the applet is written in a way that returns its data with `GET RESPONSE` APDU command. So in this case you can't do anything other than requesting applet developer to modify the applet as you want.

But sometimes it's not the applet that returns the data as described above, but it is the smart card. Actually the `T=0` smart cards returns data as such. So you only need to change your smart card to a newer card that supports `T=1` communication protocol. In this case, you have a single applet CAP file and when you install on a `T=0` card it returns data in 2 steps, and when you install it on a `T=1`  smart card it returns data in 1 step.

---

Let assume that you wrote your program as below. It has four different APDU commands (`INS = 00, 01, 02, 03`) to return the `temp` byte array contents to user:

```
package soq;

import javacard.framework.*;

public class SOQ extends Applet
{
    byte[] temp = {(byte)'T',(byte)'h',(byte)'i',(byte)'s',
                   (byte)'-',(byte)'I',(byte)'s',(byte)'-',
                   (byte)'A',(byte)'-',(byte)'T',(byte)'e',(byte)'s',(byte)'t'};

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) 
    {
        new SOQ().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu)
    {
        if (selectingApplet())
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
        short le;

        switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS])
        {
        case (byte)0x00:
            apdu.setOutgoing();
            apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)14);
            apdu.sendBytesLong(temp, (short)0, (short)14);
            break;

        case (byte) 0x01:
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(temp, (short)0, buf, (short)0, (short)14);
            apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, (short)14);
            break;

        case (byte) 0x02:
            le = apdu.setOutgoing();
            if (le != (short)0x000E){
                ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6C0E);
            }else{
                Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(temp, (short)0, buf, (short)0, (short)14);
                apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)le);
                apdu.sendBytes((short)0, le);
            }
            break;

        case (byte) 0x03:
            le = apdu.setOutgoing();
            if (le != (short)0x000E){
                ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6C0E);
            }else{
                apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)14);
                apdu.sendBytesLong(temp, (short)0, le);
            }
            break;
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }

}
```

When it is installed on a card that is communicating with user on **`T=1`** protocol, then you have:

```
Select Applet begin...
Select Applet successful.

Send: 00 00 00 00 00
Recv: 54 68 69 73 2D 49 73 2D 41 2D 54 65 73 74 90 00

Send: 00 01 00 00 00
Recv: 54 68 69 73 2D 49 73 2D 41 2D 54 65 73 74 90 00

Send: 00 02 00 00 00
Recv: 6C 0E
Send: 00 02 00 00 0E
Recv: 54 68 69 73 2D 49 73 2D 41 2D 54 65 73 74 90 00

Send: 00 03 00 00 00
Recv: 6C 0E
Send: 00 03 00 00 0E
Recv: 54 68 69 73 2D 49 73 2D 41 2D 54 65 73 74 90 00
```

And when it is installed on a card that is communicating with user on **`T=0`** protocol, then you have:

```
Select Applet begin...
Select Applet successful.

Send: 00 00 00 00 00
Recv: 6C 0E
Send: 00 00 00 00 0E
Recv: 54 68 69 73 2D 49 73 2D 41 2D 54 65 73 74 90 00

Send: 00 01 00 00 00
Recv: 6C 0E
Send: 00 01 00 00 0E
Recv: 54 68 69 73 2D 49 73 2D 41 2D 54 65 73 74 90 00

Send: 00 02 00 00 00
Recv: 6C 0E
Send: 00 02 00 00 0E
Recv: 54 68 69 73 2D 49 73 2D 41 2D 54 65 73 74 90 00

Send: 00 03 00 00 00
Recv: 6C 0E
Send: 00 03 00 00 0E
Recv: 54 68 69 73 2D 49 73 2D 41 2D 54 65 73 74 90 00
```

As you see above, APDU commands with `INS=0x2 or 0x03` and `Le=0x00` return `0x6C0E` in both cases. It is because that the applet is written as such. But for `INS=0x00 or 0x01` the return value is depends on the communication protocol. For `T=1` they return `0x6C0E` and for `T=1` they return the data.

Comment: As i think sendBytesLong() function is to return something from the card. if for any INS , code is ending with this function i.e. returning something. Will it still depend on T=0 or T=1 Protocol? could you clear that getting data from the card is depend on how code has been done [ i.e card using sendBytesLong() function for returning data] or protocol Supported by the card. hope my doubt is clear to you..

Comment: @Arjun Dear Rohit, check the updated answer. I added some code make it clear.